# Firebase upload is not getting download URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I am working on a function where I am going to upload image from emulator which sends to firebase storage. I want to get the downloadURL and to be placed into firebase firestore but, I am not retrieving the download URL. Would appreciate help.. thank you!
I am currently doing my project with firebase storage and firestore, ionic v5.

```
uploadToStorage(){
  let options: CameraOptions ={
    quality : 100,
    destinationType:this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType : this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    sourceType : this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
  }
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((data)=>{
    var storage = this.store.ref('/AAA');
    var photoRef = storage.child(this.mAuth.auth.currentUser.uid);
    let base64img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64' + data;
    var message = data;
    photoRef.putString(message , 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpg' }).then((savedPicture) => {
      savedPicture.downloadURL().subscribe((datas)=>{
        console.log(datas)
      })
});
    
  });
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain exactly what this code is actually doing when you run that's different than what you expect.  Add more logging to trace its behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
savedPicture.snapshot.ref.downloadURL().then((datas)=>{
   console.log(datas)
})
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress